# SSTP VPN Windows Server 2008 - Clients can't access Internet Through the VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras, sstp

I have setup a SSTP VPN connect and it is assigning the local IP address to the client, e.g. 192.168.0.10.  The server has two NICs, private and public.  The private is on a 10.180.x.x IP address and the public has the public IP address.

When I connect via. the client the Internet access on my local PC stops working.  I would like the Internet access to go through the VPN.  I am not able to ping the IP 8.8.8.8 nor tracert or nslookup a domain.  The tracert looks something like:

```
1 242ms   *   242ms     VPNHOSTNAME (192.168.0.1)
2 *       *   *         Request Timed Out
3 *       *   *         Request Timed Out
```

On the server I setup the RRAS as VPN + NAT.  Any idea where I have gone wrong?  Thank you.

I have looked through the similar issue at [ServerFault - PPTP VPN - users cannot access Internet via the server](https://serverfault.com/questions/41616/pptp-vpn-users-cannot-access-internet-via-the-server) however it doesn't seem to help me with a solution when the tracert and ping fails.

**Update #1:**
Also, on the RRAS setup I don't have the DHCP Relay setup, would that affect my setup?  I don't have a DHCP server setup, I just have the RRAS allocating IP addresses within the range 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254

**Update #2:**
From the local machine I am able to ping the 192.168.0.1 address that the Remote Access Server acquired to use on the server adapter.  I can also ping the private NIC on the VPN server (e.g. 10.180.x.x) but I can't ping say Google's Public DNS 8.8.8.8

**Update #3:**
Also I notice that when connected to the VPN there is no NAT mappings showing under the IPv4.  Shouldn't these be showing for the VPN client to be able to access the Internet?

**Update #4:**
Okay, I reconfigured the whole RRAS again, after doing that several times.  When using PPTP with MS-CHAP v2 authentication the NAT seems to work fine and I can access the Internet.  It seems the problem is with SSTP.  I have setup a NAT forwarding rule on the public interface to forward HTTPS port 443 to the RRAS server adapter 192.168.0.1 (as per Microsoft Technet instructions / documentation) and that allows the SSTP to connect, however it will disconnect after say 30-40 seconds.  Even during the 30 seconds I am connected to the SSTP VPN, I cannot access the Internet.  Any ideas?