# PPTP VPN - users cannot access internet via the server (Failing before DNS)

Tags: vpn, windows-xp, pptp

I apologize to be opening another question with such a similar title, but

[PPTP VPN - users cannot access internet via the server](https://serverfault.com/questions/41616/pptp-vpn-users-cannot-access-internet-via-the-server)

does not quite cover the issue I'm encountering.

I have a VPN Server setup through Windows XP. I can successfully connect to this VPN from outside my network using PPTP. However, when I try to access a webpage, it times out. When I run a tracert, I get the following result:

[image: tracert]

I have verified that "Use default gateway on remote network" is CHECKED. It does appear it can connect to the VPN, but times out getting any further.

Thanks for any assistance!

**1st Edit:

Including picture of Incoming TCP/IP Properties:

[image]

**2nd Edit:

I've enabled TCP/IP routing per this guide: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236

I'm using a WRT160 Linksys router.

**Final Edit:

The issue came down to specifying an IP range within the router's valid IPs. For me this meant changing 10.0.0.10 to 192.168.1.100 and then 192.168.1.120 for the end of the range. Enabling/disabling IP routing did not have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to verify on the pptp server that it is correctly configured for

1. routing packets
2. nat-ing traffic
3. allowing such traffic

Update: after discussion, what solved the problem was:

- configuring the network range for the vpn clients in the same subnets
  as the one handled by the router which provides internet access.

  - Surprisingly enabling routing on the xp box does not make any difference!

Comment: I sure do! I also have access to the router that the server is sitting behind, which is a WRT160N. Just let me know where to start looking and I'll post edits to the question with the related info.

Comment: Ok, what kind of server is it? Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's actually a Windows XP machine, I used this guide to get this far: http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/xp_vpn_server.htm

Comment: I did not know XP was able to act as a VPN server. I suppose that you have to enable routing on it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236 . Hopefully it will make it work

Comment: by the way, what range of IP addresses does your vpn server give to remote client? Did you opt for dhcp or did you specify a range yourself?

Comment: I enabled routing on it by following the support doc. No change. I've posted a screenshot with the IP address information. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I would try the "use dhcp" option , or at least make sure the allocated ip addresses are in the same subnet as the one under your router, so that it will be correctly nat-ed .

Comment: I tried the dhcp option, but that prevented me from connecting at all. What finally worked was to use 192.168.1.130 and 192.168.1.140 for the IP range. Since this was under my router's subnet, it was happy to send some internet it's way. Can you update your answer to reflect that the subnet was the issue? I'll accept the answer then. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's a good news you finally made it work! Can you tell us if disabling routing on the xp box breaks the config or not?

Comment: Sure, I get it working and you just want me to break it again! Haha, yeah I'll give that a try in a minute here. Mind upvoting the question?

Comment: Added a comment to this effect, but it does not appear that the IP routing registry entry had an effect on this, which was somewhat surprising.